# Jekyll ignoring permalink for title

Tags: jekyll

In my `_config.yml`, I specify my permalink format as `permalink: /:title`.

In my post, I have the following front matter and content in a file `_posts/2011/2011-10-06-articles-october-11-2011.md`

```
---
layout: post
title: Ecommerce Season – Why Site Speed Matters More Than You Think
categories: [articles]
tags: []
status: publish
type: post
published: true
meta: {}
---
[Ecommerce Season – Why Site Speed Matters More Than You Think](http://blog.yottaa.com/2011/09/ecommerce-season-%E2%80%93-why-site-speed-matters-more-than-you-think-in-2011)
```

However, this generates the following URL:

`http://www.markrichman.com/articles-october-6-2011/`

and not what I was expecting, which would be:

`http://www.markrichman.com/ecommerce-season-why-site-speed-matters-more-than-you-think/`

Answer (score 1):

What if you rename your file to

```
2011-10-06-ecommerce-season-why-site-speed-matters-more-than-you-think.md
```

Quote from [Permalinks](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/)

> title: Title from the Post’s filename